# Give input in modal a value depending on clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am using Vue.js to generate a list of items in a table. Everything is working fine. Now on the end of every row I have got a button. When clicking the button a modal opens. I would like to put information from the row on which the button is clicked, in the modal.

So, table row looks like this:
Title, price, button

When clicking the button from this specific row, I would like to send the title in that row as an input value in the modal.

Piece of my code:

```
<table>
   <div>
        <tbody>
      <tr v-for="samsung in samsungFilteredList">
        <td class="text-left">{{ samsung.title }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ samsung.scherm }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ samsung.batterij }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ samsung.camera }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ samsung.behuizing }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ samsung.microfoon }}</td>
        <td class="text-right"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form"><i class="fa fa-file icon-primary"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-form" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal- modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body p-0">
                <div class="card bg-secondary shadow border-0">
                    <div class="card-header bg-white">
                        <div class="text-muted text-center">
                            <small>Stuur ons een bericht</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body px-lg-5 py-lg-5">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="telefoon" name="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoon" type="text" value="Samsung Galaxy S9" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="naam" name="naam" placeholder="Naam" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-4">Verzenden</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I would like to send {{samsung.title}} as the value of the input with the id and name of 'telefoon'.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

UPDATE (Found the solution by trial and error)

```
  <tr v-for="samsung in samsungFilteredList">
    <td class="text-left">{{ samsung.title }}</td>
    ... etc
    <td class="text-right">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#' + samsung.title"><i class="fa fa-file icon-primary"></i></a>
        <div class="modal fade" :id="samsung.title" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-form" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal- modal-dialog-centered modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body p-0">
                <div class="card bg-secondary shadow border-0">
                  <div class="card-header bg-white">
                    <div class="text-muted text-center">
                      <small>Stuur ons een bericht <span class="d-none">{{ samsung.title }}</span></small>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body px-lg-5 py-lg-5">
                    <form role="form">
                      <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                          <input class="form-control" id="telefoon" name="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoon" type="text" :value="samsung.title" readonly>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                          <input class="form-control" id="naam" name="naam" placeholder="Naam" type="text">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-4">Verzenden</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: <tr  v-for="samsung in samsungFilteredList" @click="emit(samsung)"></tr>,
data: () => ({
value: ''
})
methods: {
emit(event){
this.value = event
}
}
Passes the value of the received event to the property you want in html,

Comment: This did not work for me, I just found out myself how to get it working :D I will update my post.

Comment: @Mxkert - rather than add a comment / update with your fix, add an answer with the explanation of how you fixed this and mark as expected, just a "self answered question"